# Manually added faces message doesn't appear in tab of accordion panel

Tags: jsf, message

I'm adding a faces message in an action method as below:

```
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Mail invalide", "Vérifier le mail");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("connection:mail", message);
```

I'm expecting it to show up at the below position in the tree:

```
<h:body>
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="center" >
            <p:accordionPanel multiple="true" activeIndex="0">
                <p:tab title="Se connecter" >
                    <h:form id="connection">
                        ...
                        <p:inputText id="mail" ... />
                        <p:message for="mail"></p:message>
                        ...
                        <p:commandButton value="OK" action="#{login.validateMailPaswword()}" ajax="false" />
```

However, it didn't show up at the desired location. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: it doesn't work @smoggers

Comment: i haven't used a css file till now, primefaces has already some cool styling tags,... but any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This has nothing to do with CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The client ID in `addMessage()` must be valid in order to get the message to show up at the desired place. You already took into account that the `<h:form>` is a `NamingContainer` and thus prepends its component ID to the client ID of the children. However, you overlooked that `<p:accordionPanel>` is also such one (and you should have spotted it by simply looking in the generated HTML output while figuring out the client ID for the message).

So, first give it a fixed ID too. E.g.

```
<p:accordionPanel id="tabs">
```

Then look in the generated HTML output for the client ID of the generated HTML representation of the input component you're referring in the message component. It'll look something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="tabs:connection:mail" ... />
```

So, refer exactly that ID in the `addMessage()`.

```
context.addMessage("tabs:connection:mail", message);
```

Comment: Solution --> context.addMessage("tabs:connection:mail", myMessage);
 
Thanks man u realy saved me !